# How to generate gradle.build with OpenApi Spring Generator

Tags: openapi-generator

I'm using the [Gradle Plugin for the OpenApi Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-gradle-plugin). The generation works well but it generates a pom.xml to be used with Maven. See the image: [pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIAnd.png)

I couldn't find how to generate a *gradle.build* instead of the *pom.xml* file when using the generator for *Spring*. There is no option either in the openApiGenerate [options](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-gradle-plugin#configuration) and neither in the Spring config [options](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring/).

Here is my gradle config:

```
openApiGenerate {
generatorName = "spring"
inputSpec = "inputSpecDirectory"
outputDir = "outputDirectory"
supportingFilesConstrainedTo = []
apiPackage = "com.example"
invokerPackage = "com.example.invoker"
modelPackage = "com.example.model"
configOptions = [
        dateLibrary: "java8",
        interfaceOnly: "true",
        additionalModelTypeAnnotations: "@lombok.Builder;@lombok.NoArgsConstructor;@lombok.AllArgsConstructor",
]
```

}

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think the built-in generators generate Maven only. You'll have to create a [custom generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/customization#custom-generator-and-template) that would generate _gradle.build_ instead of _pom.xml_.

Comment: Not always. For example, the "java" generator creates both pom.xml and gradle.build files